# Access file name from XHR event

Tags: javascript, ajax, xmlhttprequest

I am using XMLHttpRequest to upload a file. On the event completion I would like to have the filename - the server (AWS S3) returns no response with that info.  What is the proper way to access this file name?  If I overload XMLHttpRequest with xhr.filename = 'abc.jpg' I can acces it in event but seems a bit unclean. I tried setting a request header but I dont see a way to access that in the returned event. Is there a better way (and yes I can reformat my scope etc but I am specifically interested in accessing the file name in the returned event.

```
function upload() {

  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.upload.addEventListener("progress", uploadProgress, false);
  xhr.addEventListener("load", uploadComplete, false);
  xhr.addEventListener("error", uploadFailed, false);
  xhr.addEventListener("abort", uploadCanceled, false);

  xhr.setRequestHeader("X-File-Name", file.name);  // how to access this?
  xhr.filename = file.name; // works but seems a bit unclean imo

  scope.progressVisible = true;
  xhr.send(data);


  }, function(err) {
    console.log(err);
  });
};


function uploadComplete(evt) {
   // I want the file name here as part of this function's parameters (i.e. evt - doesn't seem to return anymore params than that)
}
```

Comment: Why don;t you pass the file name along? `("load", function(e){uploadComplete(e,file.name); }, false);` or make the function live inside the upload and the variables will be in scope.

Comment: I currently have moved it inside scope. This is more for my education in understanding if there was a way to even see things such as the request headers I sent in the evt - I am a bit surprised that I don't see any info related to my sent data in the event which is why I posted.